# Does EE have a community ad?

Tags: support

I'd like to put one on rotation at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

I did search here a bit but all I get are the ads for rotation here, which obviously would not include such a thing.

Comment: Like http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6082/ ?

Comment: @PlasmaHH **No**, those are the ads *for rotation here*.  Rpi.SE has a lot of crossover with EE and so I would like to make people more aware of the option by placing an ad for EE *on rotation at Rpi.SE*, which has it's own list much like that one.  There's no point in advertising EE on EE, hence that thread would "obviously would not include such a thing".

Comment: I think you need to ask this question on [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), where it can get the attention of a staffer.

Comment: @DaveTweed It doesn't require Staff to do anything; evidently this isn't clear: All I'm looking for is a .png image that meets the Community Ads criteria.  I can copy the logo from here and do one myself in 10 minutes, I just thought I'd ask quick because sites commonly already have one that's been used elsewhere.  E.g., Rpi has a lot of crossover with U&L too, so I've just used an image they already use for the same purpose (often these are created by people who are active on two or more sites and see value in the ad/link).

Comment: For example: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/4066/52138